# Generate unique integer with 8 digits in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure how to approach with generating unique integer with 8 digits in java. The biggest problem is that it gives you a limited permutation, and also the clustered env. Any suggestion is welcome.

Regards

Comment: 8 numbers???? You mean 8 digits, right?

Comment: For what purpose you need this?

Comment: _..problem is that the range will finish very fast..._ Huh?

Comment: 8 numbers is 8 numbers! It gives you a limited permutation, what do you mean it finishes very fast?

Comment: yes guys :)  It gives you a limited permutation

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. A finite set is a finite set. You can't make it infinite.

Comment: AS @Iman says, for what purpose? If you only need serial numbers (just no collision) a simple incrementor is sufficient...

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question. I'd create a service which keepa track of the last generated id (persisted or in memory) and keep increasing that number until 99999999. You can format integers to use 8 digits. For example 00000024.

Comment: About the limit, you could make it alphanuneric, instead of integer, so you can store more information in 8 characters, but I don't know if it works for you.

Comment: Check out Math.random()

Comment: alphanumeric is not applicable. it is kind of short unique ID for example of txn

Comment: The birthday paradox is not your friend here. Looking at this table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table, generating random 8 digit numbers will give you a very real chance of collisions for just 10k or so numbers. You need either full UUID or a database to coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

```
    int[] result = new Random().ints(10_000_000, 100_000_000)
            .distinct()
            .limit(8)
            .toArray();
```

8 digits starts with 10_000_000 upto inclusive 99_999_999.
The large range means that duplicates are rear, so the internal looping will rarely be idle, have conflicting duplicates.

Clustered usage: easiest is to use a database.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this will be achieved through db // @Joop Eggen

Comment: I even do not know what those 8 numbers are for. But storing them in a database allows access in every clustered server. Again I do not know your constellation.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a limited number of values, you could try `Random`:

```
byte[] rnd = new byte[1];
Random rndgen = new Random():

for(...) {
    rndgen.nexbytes(rnd);
    ...
}
```

But as one byte can only hold 256 different values the collision risk if high.

If you have one single emitter, just use the natural sequence

```
boolean first = true;
byte i = 0;
for(;;) {
    if(i == 0) {
        if (first):
            first = false;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // use i
    ...
    i +== 1;
}
```

If you have a limited number of emitters, give each a subrange. For example for 4 nodes, each node will have a sequence of 64 values.

On a more complex use case, the only possible way is to dedicate a master that will manage the sequence 0-255: each node asks it for next value.